# Xamarin Prism right swipe area change or override (two right swipes)

Tags: xamarin, prism, swipe, master-detail

Need help with right swipe in Prism. I need it to navigate to a page with a right swipe. When SwipeGestureRecogniser is aded on a page, right swipe opens the menu and at the same time opens the navigated page. Ideal would be to have swipe from left edge to open menu, and if swiped from center to right to navigate to other page. Or how to at least disable the "right swipe for menu" just for that page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: swipe to open Menu is MaterDetailPage's existing feature, so maybe you could try adding a swipe gesture recognizer to DetailPage.

Comment: you could also do right scrolling by custom effect, and I can add a custom effect to the answer if needed

Comment: Edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: Is it necessary to use the SwipeGestureRecogniser ? could not do it in some other way like SwipeGestureRecogniser?

Comment: Not much experience so not shure how to do it without SwipeGestureRecogniser. I deffinetly need to turn off the "right-swipe-menu" option for one of the views..

Comment: I could provide you with a custom Effect, you could add it to the view that you need to swipe right , do you need it to test whether it's satisfied or not